# Identifying a parent entry before I have received unique ID's from the database

Tags: php

I have created a form where the user can add countless entries to a dictionary. Each entry can have countless definitions and a "parent".

The entries are complied together in a multi-dimensional array and sent to the server.

I have simplified it here but the http request data essentially looks like this:

```
rows[1][the_entry_id]: null
rows[1][the_entry]: entry1
rows[1][the_entry_parent]: null
rows[1][defs][0][the_def_id]: null
rows[1][defs][0][the_def]: first definition 
rows[1][defs][0][the_note]: used in this context
rows[1][defs][1][the_def_id]: null
rows[1][defs][1][the_def]: second definition 
rows[1][defs][1][the_note]: used in this context
rows[2][the_entry_id]: null
rows[2][the_entry]: entry2
rows[2][the_entry_parent]: ??????????
rows[2][defs][0][the_def_id]: null
rows[2][defs][0][the_def]: first definition 
rows[2][defs][0][the_note]: used in this context
```

all the ID's are null because it's the first time the data is being entered. The ID's will be generated by the database.

***How could I go about identifying the correct parent entry?***
NB: the entries are not unique. I cannot just use the entry field.

I considered adding another row called "children". it could list the **keys** of all of the children.

```
rows[1][the_entry_id]: null
rows[1][the_entry]: entry1
rows[1][the_entry_parent]: null
rows[1][the_entry_children][0]: rows[2][the_entry_parent]
rows[1][the_entry_children][1]: rows[3][the_entry_parent]
rows[2][the_entry_id]: null
rows[2][the_entry]: entry2
rows[2][the_entry_parent]: null
rows[3][the_entry_id]: null
rows[3][the_entry]: entry3
rows[3][the_entry_parent]: null
```

then, once the entry has been uploaded and I have the ID, I could upload the value of each of the children directly

```php
foreach( $rows as $row ){
    [upload the row]
    $the_id = [get the last generated ID]
    foreach( $row['the_entry_children'] as child ){
        child = $the_id // this is of course sudo code.
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable solution. It seems cumbersome to me. What other approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the form you mentioned can be considered as a table/grid etc, It is not a http form tag. So my suggestion is sepreate the UI design from the logic. You can try a data structure with a children property. the children type is the same as its parent.
Then, when you add a ui in UI, add a child to its parent data structure. When save, serilize the data structure to a json string. 
At server side, you can initialize the object from the json. and then, save the data structure from the very top one. Once the parent has id, the children's parent_id got the proper value.
Because your data is nested data, you cannot just use one layer loop to achieve your goal.
You need a function like this:

```
function SaveDataStructure(DataStructure a, parent_id) {
   $a['parentId '] = parent_id;
   thisid = JustSaveMyself();
   foreach( $a['the_entry_children'] as child ){
       SaveDataStructure(child, thisid)
   }
}
```

Attention, above code is not runnable. Just explain how it would be work.